# Ta form + ように + phrase with verb meaning/usage e.g. 拗ねたように頬を膨らませる

Tags: grammar

> 少し拗ねたように頬を膨らませる
>
> 諦めたように小さく頷いた
>
> 思い切ったように口を開いた

Could anyone explain these or how you interpret the ta form of the verb in these usages?

Comment: It would have been much better if you had shown us what you have been able to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "(Verb phrase A in た- form) + ように + (Verb phrase B)" means:
>   "(Someone) does/did/will B as if he did A (or A happened)"

少し[拗]{す}ねたように[頬]{ほほ}を[膨]{ふくら}らませる = "(Someone) puffs out his cheeks as if he got sulky"

[諦]{あきら}めたように小さく[頷]{うなず}いた = "(Someone) nodded lightly as if he gave up"

[思]{おも}い[切]{き}ったように口を[開]{ひら}いた = "(Someone) spoke out as if he got up courage"